# On-Message Trigger working just in the Form Level?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

i'm trying to create a Form Module where i show how to use the different Trigger Levels in Oracle Forms (I have a blog).

***I'm trying the create this scenario:***
Have the user update a specific Item (***SALES_REP_ID***) and show a message (***On-Message Trigger***) in the Item Level.

Have the user update a another Item (different than ***SALES_REP_ID***) in the same Block(***Orders***) and show a message in the Block Level.

Have the user update a different Block other than ***Orders*** and show a message in the Form Level.

I know this could be done in a different way, but as i said i'm trying the show how the hierarchy in the Form Triggers works.

***What i did trying the achieve this:***
I created the ON-MESSAGE Trigger with the property: ***Execution Hierarchy = Override*** in every level as showed in the image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVSOl.png)

For some reason only the trigger in the Form Level is firing even if i change the property ***Execution Hierarchy to Before or After*** in all the triggers.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

In case you want to check the issue a bit closer, module is in this Google Drive Link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzbEh5klWdQdQmJGTDRjRFNULVk/view?usp=sharing

Data Base: ORCL (Sample DataBase), Schema: OE.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should get rid of all ":System.Message_Level" statements. They may prevent to fire on-message trigger(s) with respect to their level.